# Change standard visa to family permit unmarried partner

Tags: visas, uk, eu

I have applied for a UK standard visa 4 times; they were all refused. I was travelling with my EU partner and child a few days ago, and found out that I can apply for a family permit as an unmarried partner.

My question is, can I apply for a family permit since I have already applied for standard Visa? Is it all right to change my application as I knew nothing about family permit Visa until now?

Answer (score 4):

You can apply as an unmarried partner if you can show that you’re in a lasting relationship with your EU partner. However, unmarried partners are not guaranteed to get a permit.

https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eea-family-permit